# JavaScript - find out the source of the argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got few functions in my code, it's pretty hard to debug, I need some help, for example

```
var p = item => {console.log(item)}
var f1 = () => {return p(1)}
var f2 = () => {return p(2)}
var f3 = () => {return p(3)}
```

When I look at the console (I often use chrome), I always get the result from line x, (x is the line where I log out the value, in this case, line 1), thus, 
is there any way to find out the source of item ? and the result will be something like

```
`result is ${item} and it is from function ${functionName}`
```

Edit:
Do you guys think I can manipulate `prototype` of the `arguments` ? 
or I can do something about `return`?

Comment: Throw an error from within `p`. That way you'll get a call stack

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thx, but at the mean while, I wish my code can run smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Use console.trace() instead of console.log().

Answer (score 1):

You can't really know who the caller is unless you tell it. You could make an additional argument and pass the data in.

```js
var p = (item, source) => console.log(`item: ${item}, source: ${source.name}`)

var f1 = () => {return p(1, f1)}
var f2 = () => {return p(2, f2)}
var f3 = () => {return p(3, f3)}


f1()
f2()
f3()
```

You example is very minimal, so I'm not sure if this is a good option, but you could incorporate objects to hold your state, then instead of knowing the caller, you know which object's method fired:

```js
function someFn(item, name){
    this.item = item
    this.name = name
}
someFn.prototype.p = function(){
   console.log(`item: ${this.item}, source: ${this.name}`)

}
var f1 = new someFn(12, "someName")
var f2 = new someFn(100, "someOtherName")

f1.p()
f2.p()
```

Comment: I got thousands of the functions calling few dispatchers, this is a huge workload, any KISS solution? Thanks.

Comment: Not really without more information. It's pretty unusual to need to know the caller of a function and it's pretty unusual to have thousands of individually named functions, which suggests that maybe there's an alternative design that doesn't require these things. Usually some form of OO design is used so you have one function/object instantiated thousands of times.

Comment: unfortunately, they are all required and need separate functions, but thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**Concept:**

You can create an `Error` object and use its `stack` to extract function names (using regex for examples). Here is the concept:

```js
let p = item => {
  let err = new Error();

  console.log(`result is ${item} and the callstack is ${err.stack}`);
};

let f1 = () => p(1);
let f2 = () => p(2);
let f3 = () => p(3);

f1();
f2();
f3();

p(5);
```

**Working Example:**

The third line of the stack is the code that called the function `p`. You can use a regex to extract the name of the function that called `p`. Here is very basic regex to do that:

```js
let p = item => {
  let stackLines = new Error().stack.split("\n");
  let callLocation = stackLines[2].match(/\s*at\s*(.+)/)[1];

  console.log(`result is ${item} and it is from "${callLocation}"`);
};

let f1 = () => p(1);
let f2 = () => p(2);
let f3 = () => p(3);

f1();
f2();
f3();

p(5);
```

It also gives the location of the function (script file, line and column).